# Biweekly pandas data with period label

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a biweekly periods from pandas data frame. For instance like that

```
import pandas as pd

date_range = pd.date_range("2022-04-01", "2022-04-30", freq="B")
test_data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(date_range)), index=date_range)
```

I'd like to have a Period index with 2 weeks length. I have assumed that the pandas way to do it is the following

```
test_data.resample("2W", kind="period").last()
```

However the labels I'm getting are

```
                        0
2022-03-28/2022-04-03   5
2022-04-11/2022-04-17   15
2022-04-25/2022-05-01   20
```

I'd expect to see something like this

```
                        0
2022-03-21/2022-04-03   0
2022-04-04/2022-04-17   10
2022-04-18/2022-05-01   20
```

Another interesting point is that changing kind="timestamp" changes the values to the values I'd like to see at the end.

```
            0
2022-04-03  0
2022-04-17  10
2022-05-01  20
```

Is there any native way to get biweekly index from pandas, or better to do it manually?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Updated the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

```py
df = test_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2W')).last()
```

```
print(df)

             0
2022-04-03   0
2022-04-17  10
2022-05-01  20
```